# Scope of 'this' in Observable in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, this, angular5

I am using Observables in Angular 5, I am getting the data back from the API. Here's my code:

```
student: Student = null;     // this is at a class level

ngOnInit() {
    const id: number = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']);
    if (id) {
      this.studentEditSubscription = this.studentService.getStudentById(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.student = data as Student;
          console.log(this.student);        // {id: 14, firstName: "A6", middleName: "C6", lastName: "B6", program: "CS"}
        },
        error => alert('The student you are tyring to update does not exist'));
    }
    console.log(this.student);              // null
  }


// student.service.ts
getStudentById(id: number): Observable<Object> {
   return this._httpClient.get(`${this.url}/${id}`);
}
```

The first `console.log(this.student)` is displaying proper student object whereas the second one seems to be printing `null`. I am using `ES6's arrow function` notation, so `this` must be pointing to the class.

What am I missing here?

Thank You.

Comment: Move the second `console.log()` to the constructor. (it runs after `ngOnInit()`)

Comment: working as expected.. just read about observables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing here that observable code runs asynchronously. So second `console.log(...)` fires before the first one. That's why you get `null` output from it. You can confirm this by changing `student` initial value to something else. You will get this value.

Comment: Can also confirm by moving the second `console.log()` to the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue here is that the callback of the subscription on the `studentService#getStudentById` event is asynchronous so the first `null` console.log runs in the first tick of the event loop in this scope then once the observable is resolved then the `.student` is set.

A basic example of this is:

```
setTimeout(_ => console.log('This runs after'));

console.log('This runs before');
```

The callback of the setTimeout is equivalent to your subscription to the observable.